# How to canonicalize a coupled scalar kinetic term?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, classical-field-theory, modified-gravity

I am working with a classical action in curved space-time that looks something like:

\begin{equation}
S = \int d^4x \frac{1}{16G\pi}\sqrt{-g} \left[R - \frac{K_\Phi}{\Phi^2} \partial_\mu \Phi \partial^\mu \Phi - \frac{K_\phi}{\Phi} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi + U(\Phi, \phi) \right], %\label{eq:action}
\end{equation}

where $K_\Phi$ and $K_\phi$ are normalization constants. The fields $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are real. I am interested in solving the EOM for the $\phi$ field but this is made a little more complicated by the coupling to $\Phi$ in the kinetic term. I want to canonicalize this $\phi$ field if possible before proceeding. This is not a homework problem but for a project that I am working on.

**Attempt at a solution:**

Define a new field $\tilde{\phi}$, via
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 &  & \quad\tilde{\phi} & \quad=\quad\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\Phi}}, \\\\
\implies &  & \quad\partial_{u}\tilde{\phi} & \quad=\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Phi}}\partial_{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\Phi}^{3}}\partial_{\mu}\Phi, \\\\
\implies &  & \quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Phi}}\partial_{\mu}\phi & \quad=\quad\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\tilde{\phi}}{\Phi}\partial_{\mu}\Phi, \\\\
\implies &  & \quad\frac{1}{\Phi}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi & \quad=\quad\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\phi}+\frac{\tilde{\phi}}{\Phi}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\Phi+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\tilde{\phi}}{\Phi}\right)^{2}\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial^{\mu}\Phi.
\end{alignat*}
One can simplify things a bit further by defining another new field $\tilde{\Phi}$ by

$$ \partial_\mu \tilde{\Phi} = \frac{1}{\Phi}\partial_\mu \Phi, $$

to get

$$ \quad\frac{1}{\Phi}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi  \quad=\quad\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\phi}+\tilde{\phi}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}+\frac{\tilde{\phi}^2}{4}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}. $$

This somewhat solves the problem but now introduces this "mixed" kinetic term $\tilde{\phi}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}$. Another possible way of simplifying would be to integrate this mixed term by parts (ignoring the boundary term) to get

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\tilde{\phi}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}\quad & =\quad-(\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi})\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}-\tilde{\phi}^{2}\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}, \\\\
\implies\quad\tilde{\phi}\partial_{\mu}\tilde{\phi}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}\quad & =\quad-\frac{\tilde{\phi}^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\tilde{\Phi}.
\end{alignat*}
I thought this form of the mixed term might be easier to eliminate as it looks sufficiently close to a boundary term (using that $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu$ acting on a scalar field is proportional to a total derivative) but so far have no had no such luck.

Is is possible to canonicalize the original $\phi$ field, or even better yet both fields, starting from the original action?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your canonicalisation question, but to get the EoM from the original action seems pretty straightforward?

Comment: @Eletie Of course, but to solve the EOM for the particular problem that I am working on benefits from having $\phi$ in a canonical form.

Comment: Had a little look at this and I don't think there's field redefinitions  that can separate the terms here (although you might be able to do some rescaling of the metric, but that would of course lead to non-minimal curvature coupling). If you introduce an arbitrary transformation such as $\phi \rightarrow f_1(\phi,\Phi)$ and $\Phi \rightarrow f_2(\phi,\Phi)$ you can work through and see it doesn't look possible. I could be wrong though!

Comment: @Eletie This action originated from simplifying an $f(\phi, R)$ theory using a metric rescaling, so I will avoid going back to the original! Haha. I will try the second suggestion however! Thanks for your input!

Comment: If there is such a transformation it must be highly non-trivial, as I checked $\phi \rightarrow f_1 (\phi) f_2 (\Phi)$ & $\Phi \rightarrow f_3 (\phi) f_4 (\Phi)$, which cannot lead to a separation of the kinetic terms.